# How can I do column move in ui-grid on tap & hold?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

How can I  do column move in ui-grid on tap & hold?

I am using ui-grid for touch devices, so it requires to move columns by tap & hold on grid column header, is anyone has idea how to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Mayank you can do something like this way.

```
animateElement(function(evt)
        grid.scrollContainers($scope.$parent.containerId, scrollEvent, evt);
});

element.on('touchstart', touchStart);
element.on('touchend', touchEnd);

var lastTouchEvent;
var touchduration = 500;
var touchTimer;

var onlongtouch = function(){
    movableFn(lastTouchEvent);
};

var touchStart = function(event){
    lastTouchEvent = event;
    touchTimer = setTimeout(onlongtouch, touchduration);
};

var touchEnd = function(event){
    if(touchTimer){
       clearTimeout(touchTimer);
       touchTimer = null;
       return;
    }
};
```

I hope it works for you.